# Webform - Hide Option, Source Entity

Tags: webforms

I have a form that has 15 dates for training. I have handlers set for each session to be limited to 25 participants. Now I have been ask to turn off the registration for each of the 15 dates 24 hours prior to that date.

Is it possible to set source entities to hide the dates 24 hours prior to the date?